# Can't clone nor stage git with lfs through egit

Tags: egit, git-lfs

**Enviroment**

I did setup an test enviroment for git-lfs. This includes Git 1.9.5, Eclipse 4.6.2 and EGit 4.4.0/4.6.0. git-lfs is installed and works. Eclipse shows the right git configuration parameters set by `git lfs install` (Preferences->Team->Git->Configuration->User Settings). Git-lfs is available in the PATH of git bash and the windows CMD.

Git and Git-LFS just works fine throught git bash.

**Problem**

It's important that it's possible to use git throught Eclipse Plugins, which is currently EGit. EGit usually seems to support git-lfs, but in my case I am not able to clone nor stage (cloned throught git bash).
Clone:`Execution of filter command 'git-lfs smudge -- 'SW/xy.jar'' on file 'SW/xy.jar' failed with return code '2', message on stderr: 'Downloading 'SW/xy.jar' (289.10 KB)`

Stage: `Execution of filter command 'git-lfs clean -- 'SW/xy.jar'' on file 'SW/xy.jar' failed`

**Questions**

1. Does someone have any suggestion what am I doing wrong?
2. Why is `git-lfs clean` executed throught adding/staging?

Thanks in advance! Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating from GIT 1.9.5 to the current Version (2.11.1) helped!